# SQL Server how to optimise this query which gets related records with a max value

Tags: sql-server, join, query-optimization

I have a database view that needs to get values from two rows in a table, which we will call Jobs for our purposes here.

Alongside the main job (J1) the query needs to find the job (J2) which has the same CustomerID, but where of all such jobs J2 is the one with the task with the earliest deadline.  Please note that there isn't a customers table, it is just matching the IDs.  If this doesn't make sense, see the query below!

```
SELECT J1.ID, J2.ID
FROM Jobs J1, Jobs J2
WHERE J2.ID = (SELECT Job_ID FROM Tasks T1
                WHERE T1.Job_ID = J2.ID
                AND T1.Deadline = (SELECT MIN(Deadline)
                                    FROM Tasks T2, Jobs J3
                                    WHERE T2.Job_ID = J3.ID
                                    AND J3.CustomerID = J1.CustomerID))
```

The above query is correct but very slow: 38 seconds if you restrict it with TOP 5.  *I don't know how to optimise this, can anyone help please?*

**Edits:**

Below is the execution plan.  I've had to change it in an image editor since my table names have been changed due to confidentiality.

[image: Execution Plan]

The main view (which this will be a part of) uses LEFT OUTER JOIN instead.  If you use this revised query, the execution time drops to 9 seconds for the top 5 rows, and 10 seconds for the entire database:

```
SELECT TOP 5 J1.ID, J2.ID
FROM Jobs J1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs J2
ON J2.ID = (SELECT Job_ID FROM Tasks T1
                WHERE T1.Job_ID = J2.ID
                AND T1.Deadline = (SELECT MIN(Deadline) 
                                    FROM Tasks T2 
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs J3 
                                    ON T2.Job_ID = J3.ID 
                                    AND CustomerID = CustomerID))
```

Creating a clustered index on the Tasks table on Job_ID saves about 10-20%.

Comment: Questions involving optimization should include the explain plan.  Without it we're guessing as to where your bottleneck is and what could be done to optimize.  It also helps to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and expected results so people can play around with the SQL to ensure it functions before passing along an answer.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a view:

```
ALTER VIEW EarliestJob AS
SELECT J1.ID AS JobID, J2.ID AS EarliestJobID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY J1.ID ORDER BY T.Deadline) AS RowNumber
FROM Jobs J1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Jobs J2 ON J1.CustomerID = J2.CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tasks T ON J2.ID = T.Job_ID
```

The query then just becomes:

```
SELECT JobID, EarliestJobID
FROM EarliestJob 
WHERE RowNumber=1
```

**The execution time for 1884 rows then decreases from 8 seconds to 0.056 seconds!**

I'd be interested if anyone knows how to do it without using a view, I've tried putting the ROW_NUMBER() function as a where clause with =1, but it doesn't work - it just returns all the rows.